# I am working with atom minicoda Django, when I try creating new project I get following error

Tags: django, atom-editor, miniconda

I am getting the following error when I try creating a new project in Atom. Before using django-admin startproject ABC command I installed miniconda activated virtual environment installed Django and Python.

```
 File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\Scripts\django-admin-script.py", line 9, in <module>
        sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_lin
    e
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
        klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
        module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
    
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.core.management.templates import TemplateCommand
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 14, in <module>
        from django.core.management.utils import handle_extensions
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
        from django.utilenter code heres.crypto import get_random_string
      File "C:\Users\DELL\miniconda3\envs\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
        import secrets
    ImportError: No module named 'secrets'
```

Comment: what version of Django you are trying to install and which python version do you have

Answer (score 1):

It does seem you are trying to use python < 3.6 with Django >= 3.0.0 which is incompatible as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#python-compatibility).
Python < 3.6 does not have [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module

Comment: so should i install python >3.5?

Comment: if you want to use newest Django  version  (which is recommended) yes

Comment: python is 3.5.6

Comment: You need >3.6 as docs suggest, I have edited answer to limit confusion with small revision numbers